# Slideshow component where some elements exist across mulitiple slides?

Tags: component, plugin

Ive been searching the last week or so for a joomla based slideshow like component which supports elements remaining in situ between some slides. Ideally on subsequent slides these elements would disappear.

Has anyone ever seen a component which supports some elements switching ? One which remains editable to the client?

Appreciate any thoughts.

K

E.g.
Slide 1 : 
TITLE 1
SUBTITLE 1
B/GROUND 1
Pressing next >

Slide 2:
TITLE 1 (still in situ)
SUBTITLE 2
B/GROUND 1
Pressing next >

Slide 3:
TITLE 1 (still in situ)
SUBTITLE 3
B/GROUND 1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to keep the same title and fade in slide transitions.

Set up a regular slideshow with 3 slides. Keep the title exactly the same for all 3 (obviously the images and sub title change). So long as you don't have fancy transitions that involve movement (such as sliding in), it will appear that the title never changes and remains fixed.

You can accomplish this with most standard slideshow modules. We often use Favslider for Joomla as it is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for recommendation re favslider! I havent made much use of carousels in the past as every site seems to use them on home pages.

Btw smartslider 3 seems pretty handy (in case you've not tried it). The only thing thats put me off using it is some of the preprogrammed animations arent predictable on responsive sites (e.g. position wise). Great component nonetheless, oodles of features to animate slides just happened to be a bit too complicated for my end user